# Count is not matching in the outfiles ...(should get matching record)

Tags: python

In the tmp folder total count for PUT_LOG tag is 156 for all files...but issue I am facing here is to get the same count in the out files as well which i am not getting..

I am trying to extract first 2 parameters from PUT_LOG and dump it to outfiles

```
captive.c:        PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_RECVD_SIGCHLD, 3, INT, pid,
captive.c:    PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_EXECUTE_CMD,1,STRING, cmd);
captive.c:        PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR, CAPTIVE_EXECUTE_CMD_FAILED,1, STRING, cmd);
captive.c:        PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_INFO, CAPTIVE_NO_RAD_SERVERS, 3, IP_INT,
captive.c:        PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_ERR, CAPTIVE_GET_RAD_GRP_FAILED,
captive.c:        PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_ERR, CAPTIVE_GET_RAD_GRP_FAILED, 0);
captive.c:        PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_LOGIN_COUNT,1,
captive.c:            PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_USER_MAC_COUNT, 2,
captive.c:    PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_SEND_USER_LIST, 1, INT, resp->count);
captive.c:    PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_INFO, CAPTIVE_ADD_ACCOUNT, 4, INT,
captive.c:    PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_INFO, CAPTIVE_DEL_ACNT, 1, STRING, req->account_name);
captive.c:    PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_INFO, CAPTIVE_ACCNT_EDIT, 3, STRING,
captive.c:        PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_INFO, CAPTIVE_ADD_RAD_USER, 1, STRING,
captive.c:            PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_USR_ALREADY_CREATED, 1,
captive.c:                PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_ERR, CAPTIVE_CALCULATE_EXPIRY_FAILED,
captive.c:                PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR, CAPTIVE_EXPIRY_SCHEDULE_FAILED,
captive.c:                    PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_ERR, CAPTIVE_USER_ALREADY_EXPIRED,
captive.c:                    PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR, CAPTIVE_CALCULATE_EXPIRY_FAILED,
captive.c:                    PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_ERR, CAPTIVE_EXPIRY_TIME_ERR, 0);
captive.c:        PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_INFO, CAPTIVE_MAX_CLIENTS_REACHED,
captive.c:        PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR, CAPTIVE_MALLOC_FAILED,0);
captive.c:        PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR, CAPTIVE_MALLOC_FAILED, 0);
captive.c:        PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR, CAPTIVE_AUTH_TO_APMGR_FAILED, 0);
captive.c:        PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_INFO, CAPTIVE_ADD_GUEST, 1,
captive.c:        PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_USR_GUEST_IDX, 2,
captive.c:            PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR, CAPTIVE_MALLOC_FAILED,0);
captive.c:        PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_INFO, CAPTIVE_ADD_USER, 1, STRING, req->user);
captive.c:            PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_USR_GUEST_IDX, 2,
captive.c:            PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_INFO,CAPTIVE_ADD_USER_ACCOUNT,
captive.c:            PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_CALCULATE_EXPIRY,4, STRING,
captive.c:    PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_INFO, CAPTIVE_USER_EXPIRED, 1, STRING,
captive.c:        PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR, CAPTIVE_USER_DONT_EXIST,
captive.c:        PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_INFO, CAPTIVE_USER_ALREADY_EXPIRED,
captive.c:    PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_INFO, CAPTIVE_USER_EXPIRY_SCHEDULE, 4,
captive.c:    PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_INFO, CAPTIVE_DELETE_USER, 1,
captive.c:    PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_INFO, CAPTIVE_EDIT_USER, 2,
captive.c:        PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_CALCULATE_EXPIRY,4, STRING,
captive.c:        PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_ERR, CAPTIVE_CFG_CHANGE_NOT_FAILED,0);
captive.c:    PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_INFO, CAPTIVE_REAUTH_AND_MAX_CL_CFG,
captive.c:            PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_ERR, CAPTIVE_UPLOAD_FAILED, 0 );
captive.c:            PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_ERR, CAPTIVE_FILE_COPY_FAILED, 0);
captive.c:            PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_ERR, CAPTIVE_ERR_COPY_F_TO_SERV, 0);
captive.c:                PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_ERR, CAPTIVE_EULA_COPY_FAILED, 0);
captive.c:            PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_ERR, CAPTIVE_EULA_OPEN_FAILED, 0);
captive.c:            PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_ERR, CAPTIVE_EULA_TO_CONF_ERR, 0);
captive.c:    PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_INFO, CAPTIVE_URL_REDIR_STRING,1, STRING,
captive.c:        PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_SEND_NOTIF_APMGR,
captive.c:        PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR, CAPTIVE_NULL_MAC_ERR, 0);
captive.c:    PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_ADD_MAC_TO_USR, 2,
captive.c:    PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_MAC_COUNT, 1, INT, 
captive.c:    PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_USER_AUTH, 2,
captive.c:        PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_ERR, CAPTIVE_USR_NOT_FOUND, 1,
captive.c:    PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_ACCNT_NAME, 1, STRING,
captive.c:        PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_ERR, CAPTIVE_MAX_CLIENTS_REACHED, 1,
captive.c:            PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_INFO, CAPTIVE_CLEAR_ALL_GUEST,0);
captive.c:            PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_INDEX_USED, 2,
captive.c:                        PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_RAD_REDUND_AVOID,
captive.c:            PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR, CAPTIVE_UNKNWN_MSG, 1, INT,
captive.c:        PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_REPLYING_NOW,0);
captive.c:   PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_UPD_USR_ASSOC_INFO, 3, STRING,
captive.c:        PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_ERR, CAPTIVE_USER_DONT_EXIST, 1,
captive.c:            PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG , CAPTIVE_SYSTEM_READY,0);
captive.c:            PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_RAD_CFG_EDIT, 0);
captive.c:            PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_REDUND_DISABLE,0);
captive.c:            PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_REDUND_STATE, 1,
captive.c:                PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR, CAPTIVE_UPD_ASSOC_FAILED,0);
captive.c:            PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_LOG_LEVEL_CHANGE, 1, INT, *captive_log_level);
captive.c:            PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_CREATE_EULA_FILE, 0);
captive.c:                    PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR, CAPTIVE_EULA_COPY_FAILED, 0);
captive.c:                PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR, CAPTIVE_EULA_OPEN_FAILED, 0);
captive.c:    PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_URL_REDIR_STRING,1, STRING,
captive.c:    PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_INIT,0);
captive.c:        PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_ERR, CAPTIVE_CONFIG_INIT_FAILED,0);
captive.c:        PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR, CAPTIVE_IPC_INIT_FAIL,
captive_cfg.c:            PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR, CAPTIVE_CONFIG_VER_ERR,1,INT,version);
captive_dm.c:        PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR, CAPTIVE_DM_REG_FAILED, 1, INT, errno);
captive_radius_auth.c:    PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_RAD_GROUP, 1, INT, rad_cfg->group);
captive_radius_auth.c:                PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR, CAPTIVE_RAD_ID_GRP_GET_FAILED, 1,
captive_radius_auth.c:        PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR, CAPTIVE_INVALID_RAD_GRP_ID, 1, 
captive_radius_auth.c:        PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR, CAPTIVE_INVALID_RAD_GRP_ID, 1,
captive_radius_auth.c:        PUT_LOG (LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR, CAPTIVE_CANCEL_TIMEOUT_ERR, 0);
captive_radius_auth.c:        PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR, CAPTIVE_RAD_RECV_ERR, 1, STRING,
captive_radius_auth.c:        PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR, CAPTIVE_RAD_REPLY_SHORT, 0);
captive_radius_auth.c:        PUT_LOG (LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR, CAPTIVE_RAD_INVALID_VAL_PAIR, 0);
captive_radius_auth.c:        PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_RAD_VALUE_PAIR, 4,
captive_radius_auth.c:            PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_RAD_USR_SESSN_TOUT, 2,
captive_radius_auth.c:            PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_RAD_USR_SSN_ERR, 1,
captive_radius_auth.c:            PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_RAD_SSN_TERM_TIME, 1,
captive_radius_auth.c:                PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_ERR, CAPTIVE_RAD_SESSN_TERM_TIME_ERR, 1,
captive_radius_auth.c:            PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_RAD_USR_SSN_TERM_TIME, 2,
captive_radius_auth.c:                PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_ERR, CAPTIVE_RAD_SESSN_TERM_TIME_ERR, 1,
captive_radius_auth.c:            PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_RAD_TERM_USR_TIME, 2,
captive_radius_auth.c:            PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_RAD_SSN_TIME_NOT_RECV, 0);
captive_radius_auth.c:        PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_ERR, CAPTIVE_RAD_AUTH_FAIL_SERV, 0);
captive_radius_auth.c:        PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_RAD_AUTH_SND_SUCC,2, INT,
captive_radius_auth.c:            PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR, CAPTIVE_SOC_REG_FAILED, 0);
captive_radius_auth.c:        PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_RAD_SET_RESP_TOUT, 1,
captive_radius_auth.c:            PUT_LOG (LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR, CAPTIVE_REG_TIMEOUT_FAIL, 0);
captive_radius_auth.c:        PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_ERR, CAPTIVE_RAD_AUTH_SND_FAIL, 0);
captive_radius_auth.c:        PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_RAD_AUTH_RESULT, 2,
captive_radius_auth.c:            PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_INFO, CAPTIVE_RAD_USER_INFO, 5,
captive_radius_auth.c:    PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_RAD_TRY_AGAIN, 4,
captive_radius_auth.c:            PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_ERR, CAPTIVE_SEND_TO_FAILED, 1,
captive_radius_auth.c:            PUT_LOG (LOG_LEVEL_ERR, CAPTIVE_RAD_NO_RESP, 0);
captive_radius_auth.c:        PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_ERR, CAPTIVE_OPEN_RAD_CONF_FAIL, 0);
captive_radius_auth.c:        PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_ERR, CAPTIVE_OPEN_RAD_FILE_ERR, 0);
captive_radius_auth.c:        PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR, CAPTIVE_RAD_SERV_INVALID, 2, INT,
captive_radius_auth.c:        PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_ERR, CAPTIVE_RAD_READ_FILE_ERR, 0);
captive_radius_auth.c:        PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_ERR, CAPTIVE_DIC_FILE_ERR, 1,
captive_radius_auth.c:        PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_ERR, CAPTIVE_RAD_CONF_CREATE_FAIL, 0);
captive_radius_auth.c:        PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_ERR, CAPTIVE_RAD_CONF_CREATE_FAIL, 0);
captive_radius_auth.c:       PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_ERR, CAPTIVE_RAD_CONF_GET_TIMEOUT, 0);
captive_radius_auth.c:        PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_RAD_GROUP, 1, INT,
captive_radius_auth.c:            PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR, CAPTIVE_RAD_INIT_FAIL, 1, INT,
captive_radius_auth.c:            PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_ERR, CAPTIVE_MALLOC_FAILED, 0);
captive_radius_auth.c:        PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_RAD_CTX_ALLOC, 1,
captive_radius_auth.c:        PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_ERR, CAPTIVE_RAD_AUTH_SND_FAIL, 1,
captive_radius_auth.c:            PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR, CAPTIVE_RAD_AV_PARSE_ERR, 1,
captive_radius_auth.c:        PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_RAD_USR_AUTH_SUCC, 1,
captive_radius_auth.c:        PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_ERR, CAPTIVE_RAD_AUTH_SND_FAIL, 1, STRING,
captive_radius_auth.c:        PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR, CAPTIVE_INVALID_RAD_GRP_ID, 1, INT,
captive_radius_auth.c:        PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR, CAPTIVE_MALLOC_FAILED, 0);
captive_radius_auth.c:        PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_RAD_SND_TO_SRV_SUCC, 0);
captive_radius_auth.c:            PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_GUEST_CTX_FAILED, 0);
captive_radius_auth.c:            PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_RAD_GUEST_CTX_INFO, 3,
captive_radius_auth.c:        PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_RAD_AUTH_SND_SUCC, 2,
captive_radius_auth.c:            PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR, CAPTIVE_SOC_REG_FAILED, 0);
captive_radius_auth.c:        PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_RAD_SET_SERV_TOUT, 1, INT,
captive_radius_auth.c:            PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR, CAPTIVE_REG_TIMEOUT_FAIL, 0);
captive_radius_auth.c:        PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_ERR, CAPTIVE_RAD_SEND_AUTH_FAIL, 0 );
captive_radius_auth.c:       PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR, CAPTIVE_RAD_CONF_GET_TIMEOUT, 0);
captive_radius_auth.c:            PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_RAD_INDEX, 1, INT,
captive_radius_auth.c:                PUT_LOG ( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR, CAPTIVE_RAD_INIT_FAIL, 1, INT,
captive_table.c:    PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_HASH_USR_INFO, 3,
captive_table.c:        PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_HASH_BUCKET_SRCH, 2,
captive_table.c:    PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_HASH_INDEX, 2,
captive_table.c:    PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_HASH_USR_NOT_FOUND, 1,
captive_table.c:    PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_HASH_USR_INDEX, 2,
captive_table.c:    PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_HASH_INDEX, 2,
captive_table.c:    PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_HASH_GUEST_IDX, 1,
captive_table.c:    PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_HASH_FIND_USR, 1,
captive_table.c:        PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR, CAPTIVE_HASH_LOOP_ERR, 3,
captive_table.c:            PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR, CAPTIVE_HASH_ERR_INFO,
captive_table.c:    PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_HASH_ADD_USR, 1,
captive_table.c:        PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_HASH_OVERWRITE, 2,
captive_table.c:        PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR, CAPTIVE_HASH_NO_FREE_ENTRY, 0);
captive_table.c:    PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_HASH_ADD_USER, 2,
captive_table.c:    PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_HASH_ADD_USR, 1,
captive_table.c:    PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_HASH_USR_INDEX, 2,
captive_table.c:    PUT_LOG ( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_HASH_DEL_USR, 2,
captive_table.c:    PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_HASH_DEL_IDX, 1,
captive_table.c:    PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_HASH_DEL_IDX, 1,
captive_table.c:        PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_HASH_USR_MARK_INVLD, 0);
captive_table.c:        PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_HASH_ALRDY_DEL_USR, 0);
captive_table.c:    PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_HASH_SET_DEL_FLAG, 1,
captive_table.c:    PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_HASH_DEL_IDX, 1,
```

Please find the below code for reference:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import re


def extract_lines(file_in, file_out):
    print "file in extract_lines is " + file_in
        with open(file_in, "a+") as f_in:
            try:
            f_out = open(file_out,"a+");
            for line in f_in:
                    res = re.search("(PUT_LOG\()(.*)(\)\;)", line)
            print res
                        i = 0
                    if res is not None:
                        for segment in res.group(2).split(","):
                                segment = segment.strip()
                                if i == 2:
                        f_out.write("\n")
                        break

                    f_out.write(segment+ " : ")
                                    i += 1

            except IOError as e:
        print 'Operation failed: %s' % e.strerror



script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
target_dir = os.path.join(script_dir, 'tmp')
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(target_dir):
    print filenames
    for files in filenames:
        print "files are these"+files
        extract_lines(files,os.path.realpath("outfile.txt"))

My expected result is something like this and it should match with count:

   LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG : CAPTIVE_EXECUTE_CMD : 
LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR : CAPTIVE_EXECUTE_CMD_FAILED : 
LOG_LEVEL_ERR : CAPTIVE_GET_RAD_GRP_FAILED : 
LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG : CAPTIVE_SEND_USER_LIST : 
LOG_LEVEL_INFO : CAPTIVE_DEL_ACNT : 
LOG_LEVEL_ERR : CAPTIVE_EXPIRY_TIME_ERR : 
LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR : CAPTIVE_MALLOC_FAILED : 
LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR : CAPTIVE_MALLOC_FAILED : 
LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR : CAPTIVE_AUTH_TO_APMGR_FAILED : 
LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR : CAPTIVE_MALLOC_FAILED : 
LOG_LEVEL_INFO : CAPTIVE_ADD_USER : 
LOG_LEVEL_ERR : CAPTIVE_CFG_CHANGE_NOT_FAILED : 
LOG_LEVEL_ERR : CAPTIVE_UPLOAD_FAILED : 
LOG_LEVEL_ERR : CAPTIVE_FILE_COPY_FAILED : 
LOG_LEVEL_ERR : CAPTIVE_ERR_COPY_F_TO_SERV : 
LOG_LEVEL_ERR : CAPTIVE_EULA_COPY_FAILED : 
LOG_LEVEL_ERR : CAPTIVE_EULA_OPEN_FAILED : 
LOG_LEVEL_ERR : CAPTIVE_EULA_TO_CONF_ERR : 
LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR : CAPTIVE_NULL_MAC_ERR : 
LOG_LEVEL_INFO : CAPTIVE_CLEAR_ALL_GUEST : 
LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG : CAPTIVE_REPLYING_NOW : 
LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG : CAPTIVE_SYSTEM_READY : 
LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG : CAPTIVE_RAD_CFG_EDIT : 
LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG : CAPTIVE_REDUND_DISABLE : 
LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR : CAPTIVE_UPD_ASSOC_FAILED : 
LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG : CAPTIVE_LOG_LEVEL_CHANGE : 
LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG : CAPTIVE_CREATE_EULA_FILE : 
LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR : CAPTIVE_EULA_COPY_FAILED : 
LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR : CAPTIVE_EULA_OPEN_FAILED : 
LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG : CAPTIVE_INIT : 
LOG_LEVEL_ERR : CAPTIVE_CONFIG_INIT_FAILED :
```

Comment: and what is your actual "unexpected" result?

Comment: I still don't understand what you want. Could you clarify?

Comment: there are 156 cont for PUT_LOG( LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR, CAPTIVE_HASH_NO_FREE_ENTRY, 0);  and i want to extract this two parameter LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR, CAPTIVE_HASH_NO_FREE_ENTRY and put into separate file

Comment: I thnik need to work on the pattern search..res = re.search("(PUT_LOG\()(.*)(\)\;)", line)

Comment: @Manu What output do you get from your program?

Comment: should i need to put space in the code for pattern search..res = re.search("(PUT_LOG()(.*)()\;)", line)

Comment: out put i am getting some thing like this form LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG : CAPTIVE_EXECUTE_CMD :

Comment: in out put file my count is not matching